# Licensed File Geodatabase to unlicensed Geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase

Can anyone help me how to convert a licensed File Geodatabase "Export Deny" encrypted in ArcGIS to "allow export" if i have only File Geodatabase and  file without license definition  file.

I am in great trouble because maximum feature is disabled in the licensed File Geodatabase.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that created this file geodatabase and the version you are trying to open it with, please?

Comment: Did you encrypt the FGDB yourself, or are you just trying to break someone else's encryption?

Answer (score 1):

That is the point with licensing of file geodatabases in ArcGIS 10.3.

The author protects the geodatabase by creating first a license definition file (.licdef file, which will provide settings for the licensing) and [generating a licensed file geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/license-file-geodatabase.htm) (by copying the source file geodatabase and its data and modifying some of its properties).

Thereafter, the author generates a data license file (.sdlic) for distribution. The geodatabase and this file will be shared to users. They install the data license and access the geodatabase with those restrictions that were defined by the author.

The .licdef file is an XML file which contains unique GUID for the datasets stored within the file geodatabase. Without knowing those IDs, you cannot re-generate the .sdlic file (which is a binary file) using the GP tool [Generate File Geodatabase License](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-file-geodatabase-license.htm).

If this would be possible, then anyone could re-generate the license file and protecting file geodatabase would become useless.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't: *"Licensing is ideally suited to mature datasets that will be shared or licensed under a use agreement and do not require further editing. **The output licensed file geodatabase cannot be unlicensed to return it to its original unlicensed format.**"* [emphasis added]

source: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-licensed-file-geodatabase.htm